# django model default="" and "This field cannot be blank"

Tags: python, django

I have a model with this field:

```
my_field = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
```

I have the default set to empty string but when I create an object with `my_field=""`, it says "This field cannot be blank". Does `default=''` not imply that it can be blank? Do I have to explicitly set the `blank=True`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to set `blank=True`.

```
my_field = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True)
```

Comment: In fact, if you set `blank=True` but leave the default value of `null=False` you don't need to set `default=''` since empty `CharField`s are stored as the empty string (rather than `NULL`) by default anyway.